# CSS - Center Image at all times

Tags: html, css, image, center

I have an image that I am using inside a Div.

I was wondering how I could center the image both vertically and horizontally at all times.

At the moment, when I stretch it, it seems to be stretching from the top left corner, is there a way I could have it centered at all times.

I have searched the web and tried various things but can not seem to get it to work.

this is my html:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

here is my css:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

> **EDIT** you can see that when I stretch the browser, it
>   seems to be stretching from the left, i want to be able to have the
>   Image centered so it stretches from all sides equally*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution..!

Here is your html file :

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS file :

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 75vh;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
top: 0;
left: 0;}
```

Here is working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b3bm45xL/)

Comment: actually you don't need that much css at all: cover will override the top/left etc positions and the repeat: you can achieve exactly the same effect like this https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/7vmy2jww/ (by the way@DJONES that is not 'centering')

Answer (score 1):

`background-position: center` will align your image in vertical and horizontal center.

**Check below snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.container{width: 100%;height: 75vh;position: absolute;margin: auto;background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 50% 50%;top: 0;left: 0;}
```